# Run EC2 --user-data file only after instance has fully launched with Status OK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I have a --user-data file that downloads a few python scripts that runs a docker as soon as the server is launched.

It seems that the EC2 launch processes interferes with the python script / docker I'm running and is destroying the connection to the docker.

How I've dealt with this issue so far is to wait 5 minutes before running the python script with a simple `timer.sleep(300)` method. But this feels messy. Any way I can check for what launch processes that are interfering? or a clean solution might be to look for the completion of the launch processes, but I don't know what those processes are, or how I would check against it.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, I see ***Build*** and run docker, I think its a lot expensive for your EC2 start up,
I suggest you to externalize the build/push the image docker in other part like CodeBuild/CodePipeline/ECR.... and why not using **EC2/ECS/Fargate** solution to pull the image docker and run it with ECS agent.

But if you want to use EC2, you can generate a custom AMI with your predefined lib and packages, and in your userdata, you can just pull the image and start it

Comment: I don't actually build and run in the same script. I edited my question to better reflect

Comment: You can launch your scripts when the instance changes state to `running`. Create a rule in `event bridge` and use a lambda to launch your scripts when the instance is in `running state`.

Comment: Is not recommanded to use lambda to connect to EC2 and run scripts, you can use  **SSM Document** to run a script with cloud Watch/event bridge,  but if you can  reduce time of scripts to be packaged in your AMI, that will be great

Comment: @Hatim, My thinking was to run an 'shell' script using ssm in lambda but yeah, he can do it directly as well. No need for a `lambda`.

Comment: Thanks @Riz, I speak in general not regarding your message ;),  but the both solutions works

Comment: The issue still occurs when we reduce the build time of the EC2 instance. Something to do with the launch cycles is breaking the docker connection; So I'm not sure if -hatim your answering the question directly. Although -riz checking running state could work. Is that possible within the instance itself? Or do I have to use a tertiary source like event bridge?

Comment: @JamieChang, I didn't understand your message clearly, could you provide more info, If you want to install and run all scripts before your instance go to the in service  service state, you can use the lifecycle hook with SSM document to install, run and if all run correctly, then continue the lifecycle to have a running state https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html
If you have juste one EC2, you can use Event bridge with status change event of EC2 like running once  the EC2 will be runing run an SSM document